# returning from recursive function in python

Tags: python, list, recursion, mapping, return

I am somewhat inexperienced with programming, and I am a little confused about how the return function works. I am trying to write a program that maps a function onto the elements of a nested list. The variable levels represents the number of times nested levels there are in the list. I currently can get the program to work by printing my final mapped list, totlist:

```
def map_nested(listbasket, function, levels): #listbasket is the list that contains lists
    totlist=[] #this list will store the list after the function has been mapped to it
    for listelement in listbasket:

        if levels<=2: #once we get to the level that just contains a list of lists
            newlist=list(map(function,listelement)) 
            totlist.append(newlist) #add to final mapped list

        else:
            map_nested(listelement, function, levels-1) #recursively call for next level
    print(totlist)  

map_nested([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]], math.sqrt, 3) # my test function
```

Instead, I want something that returns the totlist, but I can't figure out how to do this. everytime I try returning it, it just returns an empty list or part of the list. I feel like i've tried every configuration of returns I can think of.

Comment: did you try and replace ```print(totlist)``` with ```return totlist```?

Comment: You say that it prints correctly, if you literally make that substitution it will return what it is printing.  You have to remember to assign that return value to a variable at the call site and print it out there.

Comment: I actually tried that already. It didn't work. when I printed the variable, it printed []

Comment: Oh I see what you meant, the print also prints "[]" for the outermost call.  From your description I thought you were saying that it was correct.  Because of the recursive nature you have to propagate the return values of the recursive calls back out, which Kaarel's answer does very cleanly.

Comment: Can you explain how Kaarel's first answer works? I don't understand how you can append totlist with a function that sets totlist to 0.

Comment: Since 'totlist' is a *local* variable, each function call gets its own version that is separate from any other call (each function has its own local scope).  This is why they can't modify each others local variables (no matter the name) and why nothing outside of that function's local scope will know about that data unless you ```return``` it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
import math

def map_nested(listbasket, function, levels): #listbasket is the list that contains lists
    totlist=[] #this list will store the list after the function has been mapped to it
    for listelement in listbasket:

        if levels<=2: #once we get to the level that just contains a list of lists
            newlist=list(map(function,listelement)) 
            totlist.append(newlist) #add to final mapped list
        else:
            totlist.append(map_nested(listelement, function, levels-1))
    return totlist

map_nested([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]], math.sqrt, 3) # my test function
```

or a slightly neater solution:

```
import math

def map_nested(input, function):
    if type(input) is list:
        return [map_nested(e, function) for e in input]
    else:
        return function(input)

print map_nested([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]], math.sqrt)
```

This is recursively applying the `map_nested` method to every list in your hierarchy. When the recursion reaches an element in a list, it applies the function provided in the original call.

Note that this works on arbitrarily deeply nested lists, and also works on unbalanced nested lists (e.g., `[1, 2, [3, 4]]`).

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. However, I am not really sure I understand how it works. It seems like appending the function would end up adding on elements multiple times. Can you explain a little bit about what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I would make `totlist` an argument:

```
def map_nested(listbasket, function, levels, totlist=None):
    if totlist is None:
        totlist = []
    for listelement in listbasket:
        if levels <= 2:
            newlist = list(map(function, listelement)) 
            totlist.append(newlist) #add to final mapped list
        else:
            map_nested(listelement, function, levels-1, totlist)
    return totlist
```

Now:

```
>>> map_nested([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]], math.sqrt, 3)
[[1.0, 1.4142135623730951], 
 [1.7320508075688772, 2.0], 
 [2.23606797749979, 2.449489742783178], 
 [2.6457513110645907, 2.8284271247461903]]
```

If you want to simplify (not manually passing levels) and flatten the nest as you go, something like:

```
def map_nested_2(lst, f, out=None):
    if out is None:
        out = []
    for item in lst:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            map_nested_2(item, f, out)
        else:
            out.append(f(item))
    return out
```

Would give:

```
[1.0, 1.4142135623730951, 1.7320508075688772, 2.0, 2.23606797749979, 
 2.449489742783178, 2.6457513110645907, 2.8284271247461903]
```